# MODX Revolution , получить ссылку на снипет

Tags: php, ajax, modx

Подскажите,пожалуйста, как в чанке получить ссылку на снипет, а точнее, передать в ajax снипет - как исполняемый файл? [[~id]] - не работает. MODX Revolution 2.6.1

```
 $.ajax({  
      type: "POST",  
      url: "[[~62]]",  
      data: dataString,
      success:  function(data) {
    
                } 
    });
```

Comment: почему не указать явно url,где находится сниппет? Если нужна динамика, можно попробовать черeз создание переменной set в fenom - если используете.

Comment: оказывается проблема была в том, что  у него не было url , тк он хранился в базе,  решил этот вопрос опцией "статичный" сниппет

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сниппетты по умолчанию хранятся в базе,поэтому я не мог получить линк на него, нужно было в сниппете поставить опцию "статичный" и указать где будет хранится файл. тогда на него появляется ссылка.